# Order rows by date collect from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

For example I have below tables:

**Table one:**

```
 -------------------------
|   UID    |    Date      |
 -------------------------
|   John   |     2        |
|   mark   |     4        |
 -------------------------
```

**Table two:**

```
 -------------------------
|   UID    |    Date      |
 -------------------------
|   smith  |     1        |
|   Nork   |     3        |
 -------------------------
```

The result  **I Expect** to be as which is order by date:

```
 ----------
|   smith  |
|   John   |
|   Nork   |
|   mark   |
 ----------
```

**I Tried:**

```
(SELECT UID
  FROM table1 
  ORDER BY DATE DESC 
  LIMIT 16) 
UNION
(SELECT UID 
  FROM table2 
  ORDER BY DATE DESC 
  LIMIT 16)
```

But the result It print is that it gets the table1 first and all of its rows then it goes to table2.

Comment: Take the `ORDER BY`s out of your query, wrap it in another `SELECT`, and put one `ORDER BY` on that instead. Something like  `SELECT x.uid FROM (SELECT uid, date FROM t1 UNION SELECT uid, date FROM t2) x ORDER BY x.date`

Comment: @TylerRoper Exactly what I was thinking (using `union all` though). Post it as an answer.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. And limit 16 is meaningless on a data set of 4 rows

Comment: Why the `LIMIT` clause? You need them all, right? Or just the first 16 ones?

Comment: @TheImpaler The question seems a bit rough around the edges. Usually I'd flag it or comment with a note about how they could improve it, but this one seemed far enough along that I'd give OP a push in the right direction. I don't believe there's enough here to warrant a full answer, personally.

Comment: @TylerRoper Yeah, I hear you.

Comment: @theImpaler I have limited the usage because the query is being pushed by java, which have made me to limit it till 16 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you separately sort each result-set from tables to apply limit on retrieved rows.

If you'd like to preserve ordering of merged result-sets you need to apply it once again. Use subquery for this purpose. You'd need to pass `date` column further to be able to do that so I altered the `UNION` to be `UNION ALL` because we don't need to apply it at this level. At higher level adding `DISTINCT` will take care of unique values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UID
FROM (
  (SELECT UID, DATE FROM table1 ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 16)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT UID, DATE FROM table2 ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 16)
  ) t
ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying: `Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY` and I suppose the `t` before ORDER BY is a mistake?

Comment: @Wajid try now. I've included parentheses. Letter `t` is needed as it's assigning an alias (name) of our table coming out from a subquery.

Comment: Now it says `every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @Wajid isn't it because you removed the `t`? It is necessary.

Comment: FYI: My complete query is: `SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM (SELECT UID FROM table1 WHERE UNIQUEID=? AND NAME IS NOT NULL AND BACKGROUND IS NOT NULL) UNION ALL (SELECT UID FROM table2 WHERE UNIQUEID=?) t ORDER BY DATE` Am I making a mistake?

Comment: @Wajid yes. You didn't read my post it seems. Please copy&paste it and then alter to your needs. You omit selecting date column.

Comment: This answer assumes there is a `LIMIT`, hence an inner `ORDER BY` _is_ needed.  If you want an overall `LIMIT 16`, then add such at the very end.  If you also need `OFFSET`, see [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or)

Answer (score 0):

I try with mysql db like this data . it is work well. Please try this:

```
  SELECT t.UID FROM
         (SELECT t1.UID,t.DATE FROM table1 t1 
            UNION ALL
          SELECT t2.UID,t.DATE FROM table2 t2 
          ) as t
        ORDER BY t.DATE ASC
```

Comment: Please tell me how does this query work for you, when you are ordering by a column that is not actually there?

Comment: It can be show your expected result .Because, order by asc mean , query will be order by 1 to  4 (smith , John , Nork ,mark )   . It you make order by with desc, Query result will be show 4 to 1.(mark,Nork,John,smit). @KamilG.

Comment: You actually didn't answer my question, but I see that you've changed your code.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add date in select query. But, It is expected result i think.

Comment: This answer assumes no `LIMIT`, hence no inner `ORDER BY` is needed.